# Why is there so much ominous music in There Will Be Blood?

Tags: there-will-be-blood

I see there are many questions about this movie. Forgive me if this one has already been answered, I tried looking through the other questions.

Why is there so much ominous music in There Will Be Blood? What is the significance of it?

There is interesting, but at the same time outright disturbing music even during rather mundane scenes, such as driving a car, construction work planning. Why?

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining. When I just saw the title of the question, my knee-jerk reaction was "well, with a movie name as ominous as that, wouldn't that fit?"  LOL.  As much as my siblings and I liked the Clint Eastwood film, "Hang 'Em High," the overwrought score would make us inappropriately laugh and detracted from the film, so I understand what you are getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Jonny Greenwood himself:

> I saw some fairly long sections of the film, read the script, and just wrote loads of music. I tried to write to the scenery, and the story rather then specific “themes” for characters. It's not really the kind of narrative that would suit that. It was all about the underlying menace in the film, the greed, and that against the fucked up, oppressive religious mood—and this kid in the middle of it all. Only a couple of the parts were written for specific scenes. I was happier writing lots of music for the film/story, and having PTA [Paul Thomas Anderson] fit some of it to the film.

[Source](https://www.nonesuch.com/journal/nonesuch-journal-exclusive-an-interview-with-jonny-greenwood)